# How to find all permissions for all users in a sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE Users(UserId int,UserName nvarchar(15), Permisions int)
CREATE TABLE Permissions(PermissionId int,Title NVARCHAR(15))
```

I Have this Permissions Table with this data:

```
Id  Title
--------------
1   'Read'
2   'Write'
4   'Update'
8   'Delete'
```

And Users Table

```
Id  UserName    Permission
-----------------------------------
1   'David'     3
2   'Sara'      12
3   'Maryam'    15
```

in this case 'David' has 'Read' and 'Write' Access `(1+2=3)`
'Sara' has 'Update' and 'Delete' Access`(4+8=12)`
and 'Maryam' has 'Read', 'Write', 'Update' and 'Delete' Access`(1+2+4+8=15)`

How to Join this tables in sql and query with following result

```
UserName        Title
------------------------------      
'David'         'Read'
'David'         'Write'
'Sara'          'Update'
'Sara'          'Delete'
'Maryam'        'Read'
'Maryam'        'Write'
'Maryam'        'Update'
'Maryam'        'Delete'
```

Comment: I posted a simpler (I think...) SELECT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
CREATE TABLE P (ID INT, TITLE VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE U (ID INT, UNAME VARCHAR(20), PERM INT);

INSERT INTO P VALUES (1,'Read');
INSERT INTO P VALUES (2,'Write');
INSERT INTO P VALUES (4,'Update');
INSERT INTO P VALUES (8,'Delete');
INSERT INTO U VALUES (1,'DAvid', 3);
INSERT INTO U VALUES (1,'Sara', 12);
INSERT INTO U VALUES (1,'Maryam', 15);

    SELECT *  
    FROM U
    CROSS JOIN P
    WHERE U.PERM & P.ID>0;
```

Output:

```
ID          UNAME                PERM        ID          TITLE
----------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- --------------------
1           DAvid                3           1           Read
1           DAvid                3           2           Write
1           Sara                 12          4           Update
1           Sara                 12          8           Delete
1           Maryam               15          1           Read
1           Maryam               15          2           Write
1           Maryam               15          4           Update
1           Maryam               15          8           Delete
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming permissions at the lower level are included in higher levels, this would work...

```
with CTE as
(
select p.*, sum(id) over (order by id) as p_level
from PermissionTable p
)
select u.*, p.*
from UserTable u
inner join CTE p
on u.permission >= p.p_level
```

Otherwise

```
with CTE as
(
select a.Title, a.id + b.id as p_level
from PermissionTable a
cross join PermissionTable b
)
select u.*, p.*
from UserTable u
inner join CTE p
on u.permission = p.p_level
```

Comment: Invalid object name 'Userlevel'

Comment: @ElhamAzadfar It was a typo